# I m trying to create a queue from stacks but I get the error "Can't find the variable require"

Tags: javascript

I m new to programming and I have an exercise to create a Queue for a Stack but when I m verifying it gives me an error:

"Queue is a class

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Queue.prototype')

```
const Stack = require('./stack'); 

class Queue {
    constructor(){ 
this.first = new Stack();
this.second = new Stack();
    }

    add(record) {
        this.first.push(record);
    }

    remove() {
        while (this.first.peek()) {
            this.second.push(this.first.pop());
        }

        const record = this.second.pop();

        while (this.second.peek()) {
            this.first.push(this.second.pop());

        }
        return(record); 
    }

    peek() {
        while (this.first.peek()) {
            this.second.push(this.first.pop());
        }

        const record = this.second.peek();

        while (this.second.peek()) {
            this.first.push(this.second.pop()); 
        }

        return record; 
    }

}
module.exports = Queue;
```

Comment: What is your environment? Do you use Node.js? `require` is not part of standard Javascript.

Comment: did you check if the path is correct for the `Stack` variable? Also, may I suggest to get the **order** of your methods straight?

Comment: I m using node.js

Comment: Make sure import path above in the .js file is also correct

Answer (score 0):

**A simple example**

```js
class Animal{
  species;
  constructor(){}
}

class Dog extends Animal{
  name;
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
}

let max = new Dog();
```